# How to let Matlab know 'NaN' should be treated as NaN?

Tags: matlab, function, input, nan

I have imported the following .xlsx file into Matlab:

[image]

My code:

```
U_sum24t = zeros(height(Z_24TimeSteps),1);
col_names24tU = Z_24TimeSteps.Properties.VariableNames; 
for k = 1:height(Z_24TimeSteps)
    col_to_sum24tU = any(cell2mat(...
        cellfun(@(x) strcmp(col_names24tU,x),Z_24TimeSteps.U{k},...
        'UniformOutput', false).'),1);
    U_sum24t(k) = sum(Z_24TimeSteps{k,col_to_sum24tU});
end
```

Following error message occurs:

```
Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I want to make Matlab treat all 'NaN' as NaN, so I can execute calculations. **What I tried already**: Replace NaN in Excel with blanks, then in Matlab > import data > "replace blanks with NaN" > not working and still displaying string format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you are extracting your data into a cell array. What I would do is keep the 'NaN' values in the Excel spreadsheet and use Matlab code to change the string 'NaN' to numeric NaN. Then you can use `cell2mat` to convert the cell array to a numeric array so you can do numeric operations like `sum`.

To make that clearer, let's break down your specific error:

```
Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

The error message relates to `sum` so the problem is in the line

```
U_sum24t(k) = sum(Z_24TimeSteps{k,col_to_sum24tU});
```

The error tells me `Z_24TimeSteps{k,col_to_sum24tU}` is a cell array, so let's make it a temporary variable:

```
mycellarray = Z_24TimeSteps{k,col_to_sum24tU};
```

Now we have a cell array we can do the following to replace 'NaN' with NaN:

```
mycellarray{strcmp(mycellarray, 'NaN')} = NaN;
```

But we still need to convert this into a numeric array before we can do `sum`:

```
U_sum24t(k) = sum(cell2mat(mycellarray));
```